# C# Service child processes frozen cannot terminate

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, ftp

I have a program that zips up files in a folder, then sends them via FTP.
I'm using Rar.exe (command line winrar utility) to zip the files. 
And I'm using ncftpput.exe (command line ftp sending utility) to send the files.

The program was working fine for months, until recently I decided to turn it into a windows service. 
I added the service code wrapped on top with the same program underneath. However now I am getting a strange problem.

Essentially what happens is that ncftpput.exe and/or Rar.exe will appear to freeze mid-operation. I cannot kill them in taskmgr (since they are under the system account - "access denied")
Rar.exe was using abotu 50% CPU usage and was apparently still zipping a file, however that file had not changed size or been modified for hours. 
ncftpput.exe is chugging along, however there is no FTP connection open at all. 
Normally both of these programs should keep running until they have completed their task, or else exit if they encounter a problem (like most cmd line programs)

Can anyone guess how changign this program to a service has made this behaviour happen?

OS: Windows XP embedded.

language: C#  3.5

thanks

EDIT: my intention for using rar.exe and ncftpput.exe was that i   could use a reliable cmd line program that would work properly, and not  have to write more code to include in my program.
evidently i shouldn't be launching these programs from a service, right?
what is the best way to do it then?
Thanks for replies.

Comment: Just a side question: why you had to make a service of a program that run multiple interactive processes? _They **should** exit_ doesn't sound like a sentence will help you to sleep tight...

Comment: i thought that would make it easier to make sure it runs on startup.       are you hinting at some common knowledge about starting a process that i should know about?  please explain further :)

Comment: Nothing hidden but you may try yourself to see what's going on capturing their output (both stdout and stderr) (eventually you may even push inputs). It's just IMO little bit too fragile, in theory a console application may even _decide_ to display a message box (or to block until an user input, such as a confirmation, comes). I don't know how this will work on a service...

Comment: thanks for your help. i believe i will try using c# zip and ftp libraries to have the service do the work instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified it to only use DLL libraries, and not external processes. Now it works perfectly.

So the answer is: don't try to launch external processes from within a service!
I don't know why, but that's just how it is.